# Mapping Duration of format hh:mm:ss attribute in JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have an excel file for driver score which include driving duration specified like 54:30:15 of format hh:mm:ss. h for hour, m for minute, seconds. I have the following JPA entity

```
public class DriverScorecard {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Driver driver;
    @Column(name = "month", nullable = false)
    private Integer month;
    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false)
    private Integer year;
    private Double distance;
    private Double maxSpeed;
    private Integer harshBreakingPenalty;
    private Integer harshBreakingOccurency;
    private Double harshBreakingScore;
    private Integer harshAccelerationPenalty;
    private Integer harshAccelerationOccurency;
    private Double harshAccelerationScore;
    private Integer overSpeedingPenalty;
    private Duration overSpeedingDuration;
    private Double overSpeedingScore;
    private Integer HOSPenalty;
    private Duration HOSDuration;
    private Double HOSScore;
    private Double totalScore;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "status_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ScorecardStatus status;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Builder.Default
    private ZonedDateTime createdAt = ZonedDateTime.now();
}
```

I got the value from excel like

```
String durationString = "54:30:15";
```

and used java.time.Duration api.
I used the

```
Duration duration = Duration.parse(durationString);
```

But got an error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text cannot be parsed to a Duration
at java.base/java.time.Duration.parse(Duration.java:419).
Any suggestion on a possible solution is welcome

Comment: According to the [JavaDocs of [`Duration.parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), this method requires a specific `String` format which is not met in your example: *The formats accepted are based on the ISO-8601 duration format PnDTnHnMn.nS with days considered to be exactly 24 hours.* That means you either have to switch the format (if possible) or extract the numbers for hours, minutes, seconds, use the hours to create the `Duration.ofHours(int)` and add the minutes and seconds later on.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)  `parse` methods accept a sequence of characters in `ISO-8601`. Therefore if you want to provide `54:30:15` argument to the `parse` method it should be written like this: `PT54H30M15S`.
I would suggest writing an additional method to parse it in `ISO-8601` unless you cannot change your incoming data from an excel file.

```
String[] durationArray = durationString.split(":");
String durationFormatted = String.format("PT%sH%sM%sS", (Object[]) duration);
Duration duration = Duration.parse(durationFormatted);
```